# SQL Server Remote Connection for .NET Core Application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, connection

I have a .NET Core application as API. I can connect it to a local SQL Server database, but not to other databases on my network.

When I try to access a remote database using a dbContext, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

`appsettings.json` for remote:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=192.168.54.124;Database=TestDBXX;User Id=sa;password=XXX"
}
```

I have tried sample .NET applications to test database connection and it is working successfully So my question is what is the difference between the database connection methodology for .NET Core and full/classic .NET Framework

`Web.config` for remote:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.54.124;Initial Catalog= TestDBXX;User ID=sa;Password= XXX " 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: There's a trailing dot in "Server=192.168.54.124."

Comment: `=192.168.54.124.`? Why is there an extra `.` after the `124`?

Comment: Thank you Christian it is a typing mistake when writing the post , the app settings file include the correct IP address ,and the connection problem still exist

Comment: Can any one support me in this strange issue

Comment: Can any one support me in this strange issue

Comment: Make sure that the SQL Server Browser is configured to start automatically and is running in SQL Server Configuration Manager.